# how to upgrade components in ambari

Tags: hadoop, upgrade, ambari

I would love to have hadoop and few other packages in newer versions that the current ambari with HDP2.6.3 allows.

Is there an option for this kind of single components version upgrades?

Comment: may i ask who and why down-voted my question? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature will not be ready until Ambari 3.0. See [AMBARI-18678](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-18678) & [AMBARI-14714](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-14714)

Depending on what you want to upgrade, though, I wouldn't suggest it.

For example, HBase, Hive and Spark do not yet support Hadoop 3.0. The streaming components of HDP like  Spark, Kafka, NiFi seem to release versions more frequently, and there are ways outside of Ambari to upgrade those.

You don't need HDP, or Ambari to manage your Hadoop, but it does make a nice package and central management component for the cluster. If you upgrade pieces on your own, you risk incompatibility.

HDP is tested as a whole unit. The Hortonworks repos that you setup in Ambari limit what component versions that are available to you, but this does not stop you from using your own repositories plus Puppet/Chef from installing additional software into your Hadoop environment. The only thing you lose at that point, is management and configuration from Ambari.

You could try to define your own Ambari Mpacks to install additional software, but make sure you have the resources to maintain it.

Comment: Actually, there is a notion of patch upgrade for 2.6.1, https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.1.0/bk_ambari-upgrade/content/performing_a_patch_upgrade.html

But it's intended for minor single-component updates for now, primarily bugfixes. So, yes, I'd wait for 3.0 or maybe some later 2.6.x release that might bring wider functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Ambari upgrade steps are well documented in the Hortonworks documentation, You may follow the below link for upgrading Ambari + Hadoop components

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.0.0/bk_ambari-upgrade/content/upgrading_ambari.html

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.0.0/bk_ambari-upgrade/content/upgrading_hdp_stack.html

All 2.6 package urls are available in the below

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.0.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/hdp_26_repositories.html

You can do single components (HADOOP -include both HDFS and YARN, HIVE, OOZIE etc,  ) upgrades using yum or apt-get or other package managers, however Single component upgrade in the Hadoop cluster is not recommended due to dependency issues - services might fails sometimes, So it is better to have to complete HDP stack upgraded instead of upgrading individual components.

Also you need to check Amabari version compatibility in the hortonworks documents, If you planning to upgrade only Hadoop core packages without Ambari, other wide cluster monitoring might fails

Comment: Going down this route upgrades all HDP stack, not individual components

Comment: @cricket_007 - Thanks for the comment !

Comment: thanks, by my question was oriented towards upgrading singular compoenents to versions newer than the current hdp 2.6.3 latest stack for ubuntu offers.